# Disable dynamic logging

Tags: centos, logging, varnish

```
Message from syslogd@dev01 at Jun 18 09:23:49 ...
 varnishd[8318]: no cookie

Message from syslogd@dev01 at Jun 18 09:23:49 ...
 varnishd[8318]: no cookie

Message from syslogd@dev01 at Jun 18 09:23:49 ...
 varnishd[8318]: no cookie
```

I keep getting these logs pop out when I ssh into the staging server, I don't remember what I entered, but I would like to disable all dynamic logging that's on currently, is there a way to do this? I am on a centos server. I think it's centos 6.10.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `std.syslog()` calls occur in your VCL code. They might be responsible for this behavior. By removing them, you'll get rid of the "no cookie" output in your syslogs.